# Change Color of Current Line Number for Spacemacs/Emacs

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

How can I change the color of the current line number of the current window in Spacemacs/Emacs?

I currently use this code in Spacemacs:

```
(custom-set-faces
    '(line-number-current-line ((t (:inherit line-number :background "white" :foreground "color-16"))))
)
```

However, this code applies to all existing windows. How can I change the color only on the current window?

Thank you!

Comment: That's not possible AFAIK. I'm curious about the use case though.

Comment: @TheGeorgeous Whenever I have multiple windows, it'll be easier for me to find my current file / line is. Plus, I use the skinny vertical bar as my cursor, so it's harder to find than a block cursor. This is possible in Vim, so I'm guessing that this is also possible in Emacs.